# Nuked /var/ for embarrasing reasons. How can I recover my Arch installation?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

How do I recover from this? Don't ask why I did this, but I rm -rf'd /var/. I want to keep all my packages and configuration, how do I reinstall to fix this and keep all that?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

```
# mkdir /var/lib/pacman/
# pacman -S base
```